# Receiving Access Denied when trying to access Amazon AWS S3 service with nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var S3FS = require('s3fs');

AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});
var options = {}; 
exports.storeMedia = function(req, res){
        var fsImpl = new S3FS('test-bucket', options);
        fsImpl.writeFile('message.txt', 'Hello Node', function (err) {
                  if (err) throw err;
                    console.log('It\'s saved!');
        }); 
}
```

My code is just a sample code I am trying to test out of the doc samples. I have saved the aws key id and secret in the credentials file under .aws on my macbook. I have already built a user and assigned it access policies such that I am able to get and put objects through the assigned user on AWS Console. What else should I look at? Obviously, I am missing something basic just need a little help over the hump.

Answer (score 0):

I researched a couple of additional things. One, I looked at the module page from https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3fs which lists the minimum privileges that s3fs requires.
Secondly, I tried to use the base aws-sdk. I was surprised to see that I could do a ListBucket without any issues. Then, I tried to put an object in an existing bucket, and that worked without issues. I am able to make progress with that, but I need to understand more about which privilege I may not have given so I clearly understand which privilege is missing.

my policy for the bucket is as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1437933054275",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1437932987273",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::meetsites-images/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::meetsites-images"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and the policy for the user is

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I was also able to find a good blog on this topic, hard to find so better to mention [a link] (http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/TxPOJBY6FE360K/IAM-policies-and-Bucket-Policies-and-ACLs-Oh-My-Controlling-Access-to-S3-Resourc)